# Django: Passing Data from Template Form back to Admin Action

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-admin

This is clearly a basic concept that I'm struggling with here but never the less here is what I have. I can get as far as selecting items from the admin interface and getting to the intermediate template page to fill in data but when I hit submit or cancel the POST data seems to be discarded as the "set_location" function never seems to be called to process the returned POST data. I don't know how to send the data from the form back to the "set_location" admin_action function.

in forms.py:

```
class LocationForm(forms.Form):
    country = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    city_region = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
```

in admin.py: (I've written an admin action for one of my admin models)

```
def set_location(self, request, queryset):
    if request.POST.get('post'):
        # process the queryset here
        if 'cancel' in request.POST:
            self.message_user(request, 'Set location info operation cancelled.')
            return
        if form.is_valid():
            request_country = form.cleaned_data['country']
            request_city_region = form.cleaned_data['city_region']
            rows_updated = queryset.update(country=request_country, city_region=request_city_region)
            self.message_user(request, "Location information successfully applied for %s serial number(s)." % rows_updated)
        return
    else:
        context = {
            'title': "Set geographic data.",
            'queryset': queryset,
            'form': LocationForm,
            'path': request.get_full_path()
        }
        return TemplateResponse(request, 'set_location.html',
            context, current_app=self.admin_site.name)
    self.message_user(request, "Control should never get here... whoops")
set_location.short_description = 'Apply location info to selected Serials'
```

from set_location.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>{{ title }}</title>
</head>

<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <p>Please set the location information for the serial numbers below:</p>

    {{ form.as_p }}

    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="set_location" />
    <input type="hidden" name="post" value="yes" />
    <input type="submit" name="cancel" value="Cancel" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

    <p>Note: The location information specified above will apply to the following serial numbers:</p>

    <ul>{{ queryset|unordered_list }}</ul>

</form>

</html>
```

Much of this is copy-pasted together I just don't understand how templates, views, and forms all interact. I have a feeling it is not necessary to write a view to process this info but I can't seem to figure out how to get the submitted POST data where I need it. Any ideas?

Comment: Rather than "fixing" code that you admittedly neither wrote nor understand, I think it'd be more beneficial for you to go through a couple more tutorials. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/ https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/Tutorials

Comment: Very logical comment, the official tutorials for Django are great, and they cover each item seperately with sufficient detail, what they do not cover is the interaction of all three together. I wish the tutorials had a few more complex examples utilizing admin actions with forms and templates the lines of what is required seem to blur when combined. I have been looking for other tutorials that might cover the interaction piece. Thanks for the suggestion!